# How to display an updated output without clearing console?

Tags: r

I need to display the changing values of various variables inside a loop (to keep track of what my allocation algorithm is doing exactly; the data set is too large to wait for output every time to determine if the behaviour is desirable).

Currently I am using the following logic...

```
i <- 90
while (i < 105) {
cat("\r", paste("count value = ",as.character(i %% 99)))
Sys.sleep(0.25)
i <- i + 1}
```

This displays the output as...

```
count value =  11
```

The problem is that the above code only overwrites the displayed output. So when we get to i = 101, the display shows...

```
count value =  28
```

instead of...

```
count value =  2
```

... where the last digit 8 is a left over of the previously displayed output.

The command only overwrites the display.

`cat("\014", paste("count value = ",as.character(i %% 99)))` can be used but it clears the whole console every time which is another problem.

Is there a way to clear the display line without clearing the console but not just overwrite? This is a smaller version of what I am doing and it gets really confusing when using large sized multiple numbers for display.

Comment: Why do you use a `while` loop when you should use a `for` loop?

Comment: @Roland no particular reason, is there an difference apart from longer code?

Comment: It's just so unusual and slightly less readable (and of course less convenient to write). I haven't used a `while` loop in R since more than a year. (If I really needed one I would probably turn to Rcpp.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider formatting your numbers before writing to the console as the leading zero will fix your issue.

```
i <- 1
while (i < 100000) {
  cat("\r",sprintf("count value = %02d",i %% 99))
  Sys.sleep(0.25)
  i <- i + 1}
```

Another solution could be to first write a lot of spaces to the console:

```
i <- 1
while (i < 100000) {
  cat("\r", paste(rep(" ",20)))
  cat("\r", paste("count value = ",as.character(i %% 99)))
  Sys.sleep(0.25)
  i <- i + 1}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `%2i` would avoid the leading zero and still fix the problem.